# Would a question about Genshin Impact team composition be opinion based?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Genshin Impact relies on building a team of various characters to leverage elemental reactions.

A question might entail giving a players set of characters and asking for ideas on team builds.

Possible answer data sources:

- https://genshin.gg/
- https://keqingmains.com/

**Pros**

- Specifically defined scope, just the characters in the question
- Should have a definitive answer based on the characters given in the question
- Could be answered based on character popularity, using Abyss data, and established meta

**Cons**

- Mostly opinion based, some players might favour other characters
- New character releases would change the answer over time, [such as this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/358547/what-is-the-maximum-power-level-in-destiny-2-and-how-do-i-get-there)
- Each new player would make a new bespoke question with their collection of characters

I would just wonder if these styles of questions would be helpful to users and also to the site to help newer players understand team building.